# Crock pot left on high for longer than recipe called for

Tags: slow-cooking

My recipe said to cook the chicken on high for 1 hour then low for 5-6 hours. I forgot to change to low and it was on high for almost 2 hours. How do I adjust the time on the low setting now?

Comment: You don't. It's done. (Probably) Check it.

Comment: Most crockpot recipes call for 1/2 the time on high as on low ... but both answers so far only subtract 1 hr from the time on low ... you should actually subtract 2 hrs to compensate.  (switch it to low, then check it after ~3 hrs).  So long as the liquid hasn't boiled off, crockpot recipes are pretty forgiving, you just have to worry about things becoming too tender & soft after long cooking.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure nothing burned onto the sides (scrape it out if necessary), and add extra water if too much has boiled off.

After that, I'd probably check it after 3 hours on low, pretending that the hour on high cooked it twice as much as it would have on low, and see if you think it's done. No harm letting it go the full remaining 4-5 hours if it seems like it needs it, or like it won't hurt.

The recipe probably isn't very sensitive anyway; there's a good chance even if you had followed it exactly you'd think it was fine over a pretty broad time range.

...all that said, a chicken cooked on high for one hour and low for *one* hour sounds like it'd probably be done to me. I'm not sure why the cooking time is so long, and you could honestly just check it right now.

Comment: I'm not sure this response takes into account it's a Crock-Pot. Liquids rarely dissipate in slow cookers, and it will likely take longer than one hour on high and one hour on low. That's why liquids are used sparingly because liquids usually increase in slow cookers. Unless you are "roasting" chicken in a slow cooker with very little liquid.  I agree that slow cookers are forgiving and times are just estimates. That's the beauty of a slow cooker. I have a Crock-Pot Smart-Pot that switches to "warm" setting after a pre-entered amount of time--love it.

Comment: @TanyaC I did say "**if** too much has boiled off." The lids fit well but not perfectly, and on high it can boil pretty fast, so it's quite possible to lose a decent amount of liquid, and if there wasn't that much in to begin with, it could have even cooked dry. Just depends what the OP is making.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd check the insides to make sure that you aren't burning around the edges. Some long cook times on high can evaporate the liquid out (even when covered) and create a very stubborn burn ring around the inside.

That aside, crockpot cooking is not a very sensitive or precise method of cooking. I'd say to reduce the temp to low and ride out the rest of the time. Everything in there is simmering either fast or slow: But it is intended to simmer for the total time, regardless.

So my answer: 2 hours on high, followed by 4-5 hours should be a fine equivalent. And you'll still be right on time!   :-)